# Monitor mapped drive failed when screen locked

Tags: windows, networking, windows-10, scheduled-tasks, smb

I have a python script to monitor file creation on a network drive mapped.
The script runs perfectly as i tested, but problem is that when i leave my pc unattended for sometime, it does not work anymore ( mostly around 40 mins up)

when pc is locked, i tested it works fine, but after a while, does not work again. 
I have a feeling that this is related to win10 disconnects network drive or sessions

i also tried to set `net config server /autodisconnect:-1`
it did not help.

anyone knows how to fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

Have to mount the drive in the code for task scheduler to run it correctly. It will work if you run it manually and are logged in, but if it were to run when you were not logged in, it would fail because the mapped drives are mounted for your user account per the session. Add the following based on your smb path.

```
import subprocess

# Disconnect anything on M
subprocess.call(r'net use m: /del /Y', shell=True)

# Connect to shared drive, use drive letter M
subprocess.call(r'net use m: \\shared\folder /user:user123 password', shell=True)
```

Comment: i am logged in, but screen is locked though. if i put user name password in my python script, that is not safe, my account has some admin privilege, i dont want to risk. any way to work around that?

Comment: i tried with your method, it did not work for me, after 40 mins network discovery is off autumatically